# Como poner imagen de fondo en un panel en JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo una clase donde tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class imagenfondo extends JPanel{
private Image fondo=null;
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(fondo,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),null);
}
public void setImage(String image){
    if (image!=null) {
        fondo=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(image)).getImage();
    }
  }
}
```

y en jframe tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public menu() {
    initComponents();
    imagenfondo image=new imagenfondo();
    image.setImage("/imagenes/fondo.jpg");
    setContentPane(image);
 }
```

pero resulta que me muestra el fondo de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero resulta que yo ya tengo un contenido, entonces cuando quito la imagen de fondo me sale asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como hago para poner el imagen de fondo,pero que me salga detras de mi contenido?

Comment: cuando haces ´ setContentPane(image);´lo que esta pasando es que estas sustituyendo el panel que estaba antes,  es decir el contedino que muestras en la segunda imagen se elimina y en su lugar aparece solo el jpanel con la imagen vacio, ya que no hay nada en el

Comment: pero como hago solo para darle diseño al panel que estaba antes

Comment: creo que debes primero entender como se comporta lo que estas haciendo, sucede lo siguiente: cuando llamas al metodo `initComponents();`se cargan los elementos que creaste desde la paleta de netbeans, luego creas un panel personalizado y pones una imagen de fondo, cuando eso pasa los componentes  son borrados, por consiguiente necesitas cambiar el fondo del panel que ya existe (puedes obtener con getContentPane), o agregar manualmente los componentes al nuevo panel. algo como getContentPAne.add(elemento)

Comment: Yo si quieres te dejo un ejemplo que acabo de hacer, donde creo un panel principal, donde coloco o establezco ese fondo, y sobre ese panel añado otros donde irá el contenido. Pero básicamente, donde establezcas el fondo, será el panel raíz donde se irán añadiendo los demás componentes.